# Хочу сделать ссылку на сервер дискорд , однако ссылка не кликабельная. Что делать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord.py

Хочу сделать ссылку на сервер дискорд , однако ссылка не кликабельная. Что делать?
Мой код:

````
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0x232323, title='Навигация по командам')
    embed.add_field(name=':eyes:Информация о боте', value='.info')
    embed.add_field(name=':detective:Утилиты', value='.utilities')
    embed.add_field(name=':video_game:Интересная игра', value='.game')
    embed.add_field(name=':hammer_pick:Команды модерации', value='.moderation')
    embed.add_field(name=':radio:Пинг', value='.ping')
    embed.add_field(name='Добавить бота на свой сервер', value='[Ссылка на добавление](https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=794873293148651564&permissions=8&scope=bot)', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Оффициальный сервер бота', value='[Клик](https://discord.com/invite/urvGgmn5Fw)', inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю сделать через [Cog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cog#discord.ext.commands.Cog)

Создаете файл, в той же папку где основной файл бота, с названием, к примеру, help.py и вставляете код ниже:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import utils
from discord.utils import get
import os


class Help(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.invite = ''# ссылка на добавления бота
        self.server = ''# ссылка на сервер

    @commands.command()
    async def help(self, ctx):

        embed=discord.Embed(
            title="Навигация по командам",
            timestamp = ctx.message.created_at,
            color = 0x232323
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name = ':eyes:Информация о боте',
            value = '.info'
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name = ":detective:Утилиты",
            value = ".utilities",
            inline = False
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name = ":video_game:Интересная игра",
            value = ".game", 
            inline = False
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name = ":hammer_pick:Команды модерации",
            value = ".moderation",
            inline = True
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name = ":radio:Пинг",
            value = ".ping",
            inline = True
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name = "Добавить бота на свой сервер",
            value = "[Ссылка на добавление]({0.invite})".format(self),
            inline = False
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name = "Оффициальный сервер бота",
            value = "[Клик]({0.server})".format(self),
            inline = False
        )
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Help(bot))
```

Потом в основном файле бота пишете следующее:

```
bot.load_extension('cog.help')#здесь вам нужно указать путь к файлу, к примеру у вас папка называется cog
```

Более подробнее можете посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/xzartsust/Tobi-Bot/blob/master/Bot.py) а также [здесь](https://github.com/xzartsust/Tobi-Bot)

Comment: зачем такой способ?

Comment: Так удобнее делать, все команды в разных файлах, вам же легче будет искать определенною команду, нежели огромный код в одном файле